# Matrix vnext vCard request

Tags: matrix, xmpp, vnext

After fetching roster, I want to send a IQ get message to get vCard. 
How to send the a XMPP/XML packet with desired value using matrix vnext?
Example of packet details: 
IQ [ID ='123' type='get' to='foo@10.10.10.11']
VCard [xmlns='vcard-temp' ]

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the docs here:
https://matrix-xmpp.io/docs/info-query

```
// construct the iq query
var vcardRequest = new VcardIq { Type = IqType.Get, To = "bob@example.com" };

// send the request and await the resposne
var resultIq = await xmppClient.SendIqAsync(vcardRequest);

// check for success or failure
if (resultIq.Type == IqType.Result)
{
    // server returned a result (sucsess)
    // => process the vCard here
}
else if (resultIq.Type == IqType.Error)
{
    // server returned an error
    // => handle error
}
```